# How do I input parameter for foundry test cases?

Tags: solidity, foundry

When you run `forge test --match-case testFunction` it works even without parameters. Why? Do I have to input them?

```
    function testFunction(
        uint64 poolId,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol,
        bytes16 trancheId
    ) public {

      //code
    };
```

Comment: It automatically uses parameters, that's called fuzz testing .

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide arguments to your test function then it will only run once.

If you provide arguments it will run multiple times with many different variables that's the fuzz testing functionality of Foundry.

https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/fuzz-testing#configuring-fuzz-test-execution

If you want to change the number of runs you can add:

```
[fuzz]
runs = 256
```

in your `foundry.toml` file

Comment: How is it possible to run when there are no arguments passed into the parameter?

Comment: Like i said eveything is explained in the docs even with examples.
If you provide arguments to the test function then those arguments will be fuzzed;

`function testFunction(address _randomAddress) public {
ERC20.balanceOf(_randomAddress);
}`

Will run the balanceOf function for 256 different addresses.
Otherwise you jut have to provide the address yourself.

Comment: If I do want to customize my function testFunction, I have to call another function and input the parameter?

Comment: Please read the official documents, everything is explained. Here is a forum to answer question when one is stuck, it is not a tutorial platform.
If my answer was useful to you , you can upvote it.